# how to set matchboxes in Tkinter, so "match all" works, but when I want to press any matchbox from the set, I can break the rule?

Tags: tkinter, tkinter.checkbutton

My problem is: I can't figure out how to set my `Checkbutton` in such a way that one of the `Checkbutton`s can match all boxes (this part is done), but when I want to unmatch any other box, it's possible. When I run the part of my code with the "all boxes" option, I can "check" them all, or take all off, but after pressing the "all boxes" button, I can't uncheck any other box other than "all boxes".

A crucial part of my code:

```
onevar = tk.BooleanVar(value=False)
def select_all(): # select all `tk.Checkbutton`
    check_buttons_list = [twovar, threevar, fourvar, fivevar, sixvar, sevenvar]
    for name in check_buttons_list:
        if onevar.get() == True:
            name.set(1)
        if onevar.get() == False:
            name.set(0)

        #below the problem, I don't know what should I write here:
        if name.get() != onevar.set():
            return name.set()

twovar = tk.BooleanVar(value=True)
threevar = tk.BooleanVar(value=True)
fourvar = tk.BooleanVar(value=True)
fivevar = tk.BooleanVar(value=True)
sixvar = tk.BooleanVar(value=True)
sevenvar = tk.BooleanVar(value=True)

one = tk.Checkbutton(
        content,
        text="Match ALL",
        variable=onevar,
        onvalue=True,
        bg="red",
        fg="black",
        command=select_all,
        font=font.Font(family='Helvetica', size="9", weight='bold')
        )
two = tk.Checkbutton(content, text="box1", variable=twovar, onvalue=True, command=select_all)
three = tk.Checkbutton(content, text="box2", variable=threevar, onvalue=True, command=select_all)
four = tk.Checkbutton(content, text="box3", variable=fourvar, onvalue=True, command=select_all)
five = tk.Checkbutton(content, text="box4", variable=fivevar, onvalue=True, command=select_all)
six = tk.Checkbutton(content, text="box5", variable=sixvar, onvalue=True, command=select_all)
seven = tk.Checkbutton(content, text="box6", variable=sevenvar, onvalue=True, command=select_all)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFJnK.png)

Comment: When you say "matchbox" are you referring to the `Checkbutton` widgets?

Comment: yes, yes I am. Dyslexia. Sorry about that. I fixed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the way to fix my problem:

```
def select_all(): # select all `tk.Checkbutton`
    check_buttons_list = [twovar, threevar, fourvar, fivevar, sixvar, sevenvar]
    for name in check_buttons_list:
        if onevar.get() == True:
            for name in check_buttons_list:
                name.set(value=True) # instead of `value=True` can be `1`
        if onevar.get() == False:
            pass

onevar = tk.BooleanVar(value=False)
twovar = tk.BooleanVar(value=False)
threevar = tk.BooleanVar(value=False)
fourvar = tk.BooleanVar(value=False)
fivevar = tk.BooleanVar(value=False)
sixvar = tk.BooleanVar(value=False)
sevenvar = tk.BooleanVar(value=False)
```